# Detail in proof of Künneth's formula in Hatcher

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Im currently reading Hatcher's book on algebraic topology and don't understand the following statement in the proof of the theorem he calls the algebraic version of the Künneth formula (page $274$).

> Theorem: If $R$ is a PID and the $R$-modules $C_i$ are free, then there is a natural short exact sequence $$
> 0 \to \bigoplus_i (H_i(C) \otimes_R H_{n-i}(C')) \to H_n(C \otimes_R C') \to \bigoplus_i \mathrm{Tor}_R(H_i(C),H_{n-i-1}(C') \to 0
> $$ and this sequence splits.

In the proof he first considers the special case in which all the boundary maps in $C$ are zero. He then states that $C \otimes_R C'$ is given by the direct sum of the complexes $C_i \otimes_R C'$. I do not see this fact however. What complex does he mean exactly? Does he mean the complex with $C_i \otimes_R C'_n$ in degree $n$? Because if that is the case I dont see why $C \otimes_R C'$ is equal to the direct sum of those. Furthermore I wondered if the sum of direct complexes is given by the sum of the boundary maps and the direct sum of modules in each degree? The definition I use for the tensor product of complexes is: $$(C \otimes_R C')_n:= \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}(C_i \otimes_R C'_{n-i})
$$ in the $n$-th degree.

Answer (score 2):

Hatcher's notation is indeed imprecise becauce he does not properly define $C_i \otimes_R C'$. In this tensor product I think he understands $C_i$ as the chain complex having the $R$-module $C_i$ in dimension $i$ and $0$ in all other dimensions. Thus $(C_i \otimes_R C')_n = C_i \otimes C'_{n-i}$ and therefore
$$\bigoplus_i C_i \otimes_R C' = C \otimes_R C' .$$